# Continuously Tracking and storing 6D pose of an object in Gazebo simulation

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am currently working on a drone related project and using gazebo for simulation

In order to measure accuracy of my localisation, I need to know the **ground truth** values.
Is there some way in Gazebo to **continuously track/store** the actual/true/ground truth 6D pose,
ie the rotation and translation w.r.t. to a fixed frame like the world frame.

I wish to create something like the following -

[image: image description]

Thanks a lot !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18943/continuously-tracking-and-storing-6d-pose-of-an-object-in-gazebo-simulation./) by [malhar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4549/malhar/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 19 on 2018-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

While @smorad's answer helped , the mentioned topic (`/gazebo/model_states`) did not provide timing values. Also it provides the actual pose for all models and hence requiring additional filtering for finding the actual pose of the desired object.

If using Gazebo + ROS, the `/ground_truth/state` topic can be enabled in the URDF ( as seen [here](http://sauravag.com/2017/06/how-to-get-ground-truth-pose-data-in-ros-gazebo/) and [here](http://docs.ros.org/electric/api/gazebo_plugins/html/group__GazeboRosP3D.html) )  of the required ROS robot ( which is then converted to a Gazebo model in the generated SDF file), making it the required solution.

---

Originally posted by [malhar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4549/malhar/) with karma: 19 on 2018-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You should be able to use `gz topic` for this. You should take a look at the different topics, I think one of them may be `model_state` or something that will contain pose data.

---

Originally posted by [smorad](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4914/smorad/) with karma: 13 on 2018-04-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malhar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4549/malhar/) on 2018-04-09**:
Thanks a lot for the info, I will look into it soon and mark this as the answer if it works out. Might take a day or two.

**Comment by [malhar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4549/malhar/) on 2018-04-09**:
Hi, I tried using it and it's almost what I want but unfortunately I've run into an issue. The topic does not have any timing information and hence if I want to plot it against my current estimate (as shown in image above), I want it to be at the same time instant ( or approximately close). Any clue on how to deal with this ?

**Comment by [malhar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4549/malhar/) on 2018-04-09**:
Should I try using the `/ground_truth/state` topic instead ?

**Comment by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) on 2018-04-10**:
Are you using ROS alongside Gazebo? Ros topics also have timing information attached to them.

**Comment by [malhar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4549/malhar/) on 2018-04-10**:
Hi yes I am using Gazebo + ROS , but I needed  a topic that provides both - the ground truth and timing values.